# one to one polymorphic table structure in laravel with sql

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm using Laravel 8 trying to create a database design with something that turns out to be one to one polymorphic relationship (never use it before). But seeing Laravel's documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one-polymorphic-table-structure), I  can't help to wonder why not making the tables with one to one polymorphic relationship like this:

```
images
    id - integer
    url - string
    imageable_type - string

posts
    image_id - integer
    name - string
 
users
    image_id - integer
    name - string
```

with `image_id` in `posts` and `users` set as foreign-primary key which refers to `images`'s `id`. The idea behind this approach is because the relation between these tables is one to one, thus `posts` and `users` don't really need their own id.

Also, this approach will allow me to add constrain to `image_id` with

```php
$table->foreignId('image_id')->constrained();
$table->unique(['image_id']);
```

I believe that this is doable. But, what's your insight about this? Is there something I miss by using this approach? Do you think this is future proof, like if a new child model is added in the future? Which one would you choose between this approach and the one Laravel wrote in its documentation?

### Edit

Reading @AlexMax's comment, I now realize that my concept IS flipped! Laravel's example considers the `images` as the child; while in my paradigm, `posts` and `users` are considered as the children. Maybe I should change the example case to this:

```
documents
    id - integer
    type- string
    document_type - string

document_type_a
    document_id - integer
    name - string
 
document_type_b
    document_id - integer
    name - string
```

with a side note: every time new `documents` are created, it will then create a new record for one of its children (handled by the app). In this case, the children are `document_type_a` and `document_type_b`. Which one is used will be determined based on the `type` of `documents`.

So, back to the question: what do you think?

Plus: is this still considered a polymorphic relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take this approach, however I believe in future proofing. By creating primary uuid would potentially give you flexibility in the future. You're also creating a inverse dependency saying that if a user exists it must have an image_id. Whether or not that is the intention it will most likely be read that way by design. What I mean by future proofing is that you would want to be closed for modification in your db and open for extension. For example if you just have a polymorphic table and the create primary keys you won't have to modify pre existing code but rather create a new class, table (for that class), and a relationship without changing a line of code in the image class they way you are currently doing it image needs to be aware. So you would be force to have a trait for every class that has an image associated with it. You also lose the history of images. For instance a user changes their profile picture you only have a reference to the last image vs a history of images.

Comment: Your thought is good but flipped

Comment: Also if things are one to one you don't need a polymorphic table (which is mostly concerned with the reference table, in your example imagable type) just create an image table with a nullable relationship without a fk. However at the end of the day how often are you going to need an image and work back to the higher object? I would assume you would most likely have a user object and grab that users image

Comment: I just realize that my thought IS flipped! Please re-read the post as I have added more explanation to it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ya so it's not, a polymorphic relationship because the dependency is inversed. If you simply had a table that has imageable_id and imageable_type then basically anything can have an image associated with it. When you add a column to anything you want to associate with an image you create a dependency or or a reliance that class or table needs to be aware of that dependcy.

Comment: Jeffery way has a good example in his solid principle tutorial. S being single responsibility and o being open-closed. But combing the two basically says that classes and things should only be aware of themselves but created in a way that they can be extended without having to go and change original design.

Comment: The quest and desire is that you create something that 10 years from now witholds but is designed in such a manner that someone can patch it or improve upon it only by seeing the design. Hence interfaces and dependency injection. Or else many people will misuse or attempt to rewrite the perfect wheel you created.

Comment: I don't understand what's "Jefferey's solid principle tutorial" you mentioned about. Can you give me a link or something?

Comment: Anyway, your insight had cleared my curiosity. I'm marking it as answered. Thanks again.